# I cannot run python runtests.py -v for testing numpy it giving me version issue

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing, numpy-ufunc

I want to run  test for numpy library in my local machine but when I simple testing command
like  this command

```
python runtests.py -v
```

I am keep getting following error
`

```
Building, see build.log...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/ishaque/b2681382-1a01-486d-8f51-52e6a9a56864/open source/numpy/setup.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(f'Cannot parse version {FULLVERSION}')
RuntimeError: Cannot parse version 0+untagged.32104.g2a66cbb

Build failed!
```

I have follwing library install with there version

```
attrs==23.1.0
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
coverage==7.2.3
Cython==0.29.34
hypothesis==6.24.1
iniconfig==2.0.0
mypy==0.981
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
numpy==1.24.3
packaging==23.1
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.11.0
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-cov==3.0.0
pytz==2021.3
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.5.0
```

So can anyone tell how to solve this problem
Thanks in advance.

I have test changed python's version but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's `setup.py` first checks the git tags in the repository and searches for a tagged version to use. If no tags exist, it uses the current commit, which is untagged, hence the error.  In order to pull the tags from main, you have to run

```
git pull upstream main --tags
```

Numpy 1.24.3 didn't have the `--tags` flag in its [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/dev/index.html) yet, but will in the next release.